# не работает SceneManager.LoadScene

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый день всем. Появилась проблема: сделал **кнопки** на двух сценах, чтобы можно было **переходить между ними**. **Они работали и я про них забыл**. Но потом я куда-то залез и все полетело к чертям.

Библиотека `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement` используется, а `SceneManager.LoadScene("...")` пишет "*Scene manager не содержит определения для Load*". Пишу `SceneManager`, ставлю точку и вообще ничего на L нету. Хотя до этого все работало.

Лазил где-то в командах `Don'tDestroyOnLoad(gameobject)`. Мб это оно как-то все испортило. Вообщем не знаю, почти сделал 1ый проект и тут такое... Подскажите кто чем может.

**Интересный момент**: если создаю новый проект и пробую писать там `SceneManager.LoadScene("...")`, то все работает, а если переношу туда скрипт из "проблемного" проекта, то проявляется та же проблема.

Код скрипта:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class quality: MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown() {
        switch (gameObject.name) {
            case "Bad":
                QualitySettings.currentLevel = QualityLevel.Fastest;
                break;
            case "Norm":
                QualitySettings.currentLevel = QualityLevel.Simple;
                break;
            case "Good":
                QualitySettings.currentLevel = QualityLevel.Fantastic;
                break;
            case "Back":
                SceneManager.LoadScene("1ая игра норм");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код ваш тогда...... какая версия Unity используется? Какая IDE? Какие-нибудь ошибки пишет в консоли, когда нажимаешь сохранить скрипт с `SceneManager.LoadScene`? Комп, юнити перезагружал? ... может дело в кодировке или в том, что вместо английской буквы где-то затесалась русская (или еще какая) и попробовать переписать скрипт/проблемный участок

Comment: Version 5.4.4p2 Personal, IDE -Mono, Ошибка: "SceneManager" не содержит определения для "LoadScene". Комп перезагружал. Русских букв нету.

Comment: `using UnityEngine;using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class quality : MonoBehaviour {
void OnMouseDown ()
 {switch (gameObject.name) {
case "Bad":QualitySettings.currentLevel = QualityLevel.Fastest;
          break;
case "Norm":QualitySettings.currentLevel=QualityLevel.Simple;           break;
case"Good":QualitySettings.currentLevel= QualityLevel.Fantastic; break;                                              case"Back":SceneManager.LoadScene("1ая игра норм");break;}}}`

Comment: Ну а если в новом проекте вот этот код написать с нуля ручками и скопировать в текущий, то что будет?

Comment: вот только самого такая идея посетила, сейчас попробуем.

Comment: Было такое. Помог простой релоад проекта.

Comment: Перенос из другого проекта не помог. В только что созданном проекте все работает, при переносе та же ошибка=(

Comment: И еще заметил, SceneManager.LoadScene ("...") - находит LoadScene только, если это написано вне функции(метода).

Comment: Все заработало. Использовал Application.LoadLevel(1); Хоть оно и писало, что команда устарела и советовала использовать SceneManager.LoadScene("...").

Comment: А в текущем проекте много всего? что если примерно как написал @Pepsi4 - взять, дропнуть всё, кроме папки assets, создать новый проект, и туда закинуть файлы?вообще, магия, конечно)

Comment: Я пробовал. Если в другом проекте все ручками писать, тогда все норм. Но если перекидываешь скрипт - то все повторятся и снова вылазит ошибка. Вообщем всем огромное спасибо. Не думал, что кто-то будет помогать.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы создали скрипт с названием SceneManager. Тогда unity пробуем искать именно в вашем скрипте, где такой функции, разумеется, нет. На картинке ниже я создал скрипт с таким названием в одном проекте и сразу вылезли 3 ошибки. Проблему решить можно двумя способами:

1. более быстрый- переименовать свой скрипт. (Переименовать надо как в коде, так и название в юнити.)
2. если по какой то причине хотите всё-таки использовать название SceneManager, нужно будет указывать в каждом конкретном случае,  что вы желаете использовать класс SceneManager не свой, а из библиотеки unity. Например: UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("level1");

   [image: Ошибки при совпадении имен]

Answer (score 0):

Вы не перемещали сцены в другие папки? У меня так было из за того что сцену кинул в другую папку. После того как по новой добавил ее в build setings все заработало.